# Deploy Node application no Heroku com ES6 modules?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, heroku

Fala, devs!

Seguinte...

Gostaria de saber como faço para fazer um deploy de uma aplicação NodeJS usando ES6 Modules

No meu package.json estou usando assim:

```
"type": "module",
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon --es-module-specifier-resolution=node src",
    "start": "--es-module-specifier-resolution=node src"
  },
```

Para o nodemon reconhecer os módulos tive que adicioanr o conteúdo `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` no dev

Para o PM2 reconhcer preciso adicionar o node_ags `node_args: "--es-module-specifier-resolution=node",` para poder ele reconhecer os módulos

Seguindo os passos [desse documento](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local), deparei com o comando `heroku local web`

Onde eu executar o comando tenho o seguinte retorno

```
'--es-module-specifier-resolution' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
```

Mas se tiro o `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` do start ele não reconhece os módulos

```
 Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
```

Como faço para adicionar esse node_args ou fazer com que o heroku aceite módulos?

Comment: O seu script start está correto? Não falta a palavra `node` ou `nodemon` antes dos argumentos?

Comment: Qual o valor da propriedade [`type`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_json_and_file_extensions) no seu `package.json`?

Comment: Deve ser o "start" que esta errado

Comment: @LuizFelipe o valor da propriedade type é module

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pois é, é o start que eu preciso saber a forma correta de como o heroku reconheça

Comment: @Danizavtz Acertou! Isso mesmo!! Faltava algo antes do argumentos.. Era a node

Comment: Opa, blz. Votei para fechar porque foi apenas um erro, que bom que foi resolvido.

Comment: Blz! Já vi perguntas no forum em inglès que não está respondida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em seu arquivo `package.json` você está esquecendo de colocar a palavra `node` ou `nodemon`.

Repare com atenção a seguinte linha que você está declarando:

```
 "start": "--es-module-specifier-resolution=node src"
```

Como deveria ser:

```
 "start": "node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node src"
```